# how to make API call in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudtrail

How API call works in AWS in situation like this: Suppose two different user in AWS want to create separate S3 bucket according to their name using API call for EC2. user will not provide any bucket name manually at bucket creation time. bucket name should be assigned automatically according to user name. Example is given below.

-> 1st user name : a;

-> 2nd user name : b;

-> bucket to be created by "a" is: a-s3-bucket;

-> bucket to be created by "b" is: b-s3-bucket;

if suppose another user 3 is also there named "x", then the bucket created by "x" by AWS API call should be "x-s3-bucket"

So here how API call is made in AWS? what are the options? where API should be integrated? And where amazon Cloud trail stands in this situation?

Thank you for your help in advance. I am a newbie in AWS API call.

Comment: This is a very broad question and I'm not sure where to start.  There are [examples of bucket creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/create-bucket-get-location-example.html) in a variety of programming languages showing how to access the API.  Cloudtrail is a logging system that helps you audit who did what and is commonly used for things like compliance auditing.  It doesn't directly affect bucket creation but that could be an even that is tracked with Cloudtrail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awscli` to do this.

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket "$(aws opsworks describe-my-user-profile --output json | jq -r ".UserProfile.Name")-s3-bucket"
```

In command above, `aws opsworks describe-my-user-profile --output json | jq -r ".UserProfile.Name"` gives aws username.